# ImageDataGenerator.flow_from_directory to a dataset that can be used in Kfold

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras, k-fold

I am trying to use the cross validation approach for the model I use for classifying images into 3 classes. I use the following code to import images:

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
data = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(directory=train_path,
                                       target_size=(300,205), batch_size=8, 
                                       color_mode='grayscale',class_mode='categorical')
```

It worked fine to train the model and test it before I tried using `sklearn.model_selection`'s `KFold`. All the examples I find on the internet are simple numpy arrays, whereas I have a classification array. Meaning that the arrays of images have labels and I could not work anything around to convert this `DirectoryIterator` (flow_from_directory returns a DirectoryIterator) into an array that can be used with `kfold.split` function.

I tried the following approaches, please bear in mind I am new to classification models:

```
np_data = data.next()

num_folds = 5
kfold = KFold(n_splits=num_folds, shuffle=True)
for train, test in kfold.split(np_data):
```

Then I get:
*ValueError: Cannot have number of splits n_splits=5 greater than the number of samples: n_samples=2.*

I believe I get this value error because `np_array` has 2 nested arrays inside, first for the images and second for their classes.

I would try to shuffle and kfold only the images, but then without the information what class they belong to I cannot train my model properly. I have tried following the guide in [this link](https://www.machinecurve.com/index.php/2020/02/18/how-to-use-k-fold-cross-validation-with-keras/#adding-k-fold-cross-validation) but the data for their testing and training seem to be imported in a different way than I have my data. Then I came across also [this](https://machinelearningmastery.com/cross-validation-for-imbalanced-classification/), but again it did not really help with my situation.

I have no idea what I am missing, any additional help will be much appreciated.

Lastly I have tried doing:

```
x, y = data.next()
for train, test in kfold.split(x, y):
     ...
```

This gives me the following error when it begins the first epoch of the first fold:

*ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable: ['conv2d/kernel:0', 'conv2d/bias:0', 'conv2d_1/kernel:0', 'conv2d_1/bias:0', 'conv2d_2/kernel:0', 'conv2d_2/bias:0', 'conv2d_3/kernel:0', 'conv2d_3/bias:0', 'dense/kernel:0', 'dense/bias:0', 'dense_1/kernel:0', 'dense_1/bias:0'].*

Comment: Using x[train], y[train] and x[test], y[test] seems to work but I would like to be sure. I will update and post an answer if this is the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason I got the last *ValueError* was because I did not include `y[test]` when I used `model.fit()`. The following worked fine for me.

After importing the images with `ImageDataGenerator.flow_from_directory(...)`, `x, y = data.next()` yields images and their label into x and y arrays. Henceforth:

```
kfold = KFold(n_splits=num_folds, shuffle=True)

fold_no = 1
for train, test in kfold.split(x, y):
   model = keras.models.Sequential(.....)
   model.fit(x[train], y[train], epochs=epochs)
   ...
   scores = model.evaluate(x[test], y[test], verbose=0)
   ...
   fold_no = fold_no + 1
```

I also used this print line to keep track of the scores:

```
print(f'Score for fold {fold_no}: {network.metrics_names[0]} of {scores[0]}; {network.metrics_names[1]} of {scores[1]*100}%')
```

Additionally, loss and accuracy results can be stored in two separate arrays and get an average at the end of the folds.

```
acc_per_fold.append(scores[1] * 100)
loss_per_fold.append(scores[0])
```

The above 2 lines have to be inside the for loop (`for train, test in kfold.split(x, y):`), and the below lines outside of it.

```
print("\n\n Overall accuracy: " + str(np.average(acc_per_fold)))
print("Overall loss: " + str(np.average(loss_per_fold)))
```

Comment: what is "network" variable?

Comment: @user836026 `models.Sequential()` and models is imported from keras: `from keras import models`

Answer (score 1):

On this line

> x, y = data.next()

Here  it's only yielding only the single batch of data as your batch_size=8. If you print len(data.next()[0]) you can see the size will be 8. I think we don't want to only use the single batch data. So at first I extracted all data to numpy array.

```
x=np.concatenate([train_generator.next()[0] for i in range(train_generator.__len__())])
y=np.concatenate([train_generator.next()[1] for i in range(train_generator.__len__())])
```

Then I applied kfold_split

```
for train, test in kf.split(x, y):
    print(f"Fold {fold_no}/{k}")
    history = model.fit(x[train], y[train], epochs=5, validation_data=(x[test], y[test]))
```

@Jacqueline Thanks your code helped me a lot